# jsp:include throws IllegalStateException in App Engine Managed VM Java runtime

Tags: java, jsp, google-app-engine, google-compute-engine

Managed VM throws an IllegalStateException whenever there is a `jsp:include`

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
 at org.apache.jasper.runtime.ServletResponseWrapperInclude.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapperInclude.java:65)
 at javax.servlet.ServletResponseWrapper.getOutputStream(ServletResponseWrapper.java:94)
 at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.CommitDelayingResponse.<init>(CommitDelayingResponse.java:62)
 at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.CommitDelayingResponseServlet3.<init>(CommitDelayingResponseServlet3.java:23)
 at com.google.apphosting.vmruntime.jetty9.VmRuntimeWebAppContext.doScope(VmRuntimeWebAppContext.java:394)
...
```

I forked the hello app to show the error : https://github.com/erugeri/appengine-java-vm-hello/compare/jsp-include-bug?diff=unified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See a possible solution to test at:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-java-vm-hello/issues/2#issuecomment-64992080